# Is it possible to write to the same file from different methods?

Tags: java, java-io

I have the following method:

```
public static void writeContestantsToFile(ArrayList<Contestant> contestants) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("minos.dat");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    oos.writeObject(contestants);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
}
```

But I am wondering whether or not I can write to the file minos.dat again with another arraylist? For example have another method like this:

```
public static void writeContestantsToFile(ArrayList<Times> times) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("minos.dat");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    oos.writeObject(times);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
}
```

Will I be able to retrieve both the times arraylist and contestants? Or do I need to write to separate files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but if you don't want to override the content of the file, but only append, open it like that:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("minos.dat", true);
```

(using [this constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29))

Comment: This won't work for `ObjectOutputStreams`. You will get a `StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code AC` when you read over the join.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean sequentially in one thread then you use @MByD solution. Its called appending. If this is multithreaded then you will need to block and synchronize.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the case of object streams. Without special measures you cannot append to a file using object output streams. You must:

- leave the file open
- synchronize access to it
- use the same `ObjectOutputStream` for the life of the process
- and ensure it is closed when you exit.